# iPhone4 blurred text/images after content load via ajax

Tags: iphone, cordova, retina-display

i use phonegap, jqtouch and iScoll for a iphone app. 
I load some content via ajax into a div container. After that, sometimes all elements blurred and sometimes not.

Strangely after i make a swap (-webkit-transform: perspective(800);) between pages, all looks sharp.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Thanks Kevin
and sorry for the bas english

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar problem. The advice here helped...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iscroll/DuZ5I-77fxo

Comment: Thank you Sid, I had problems with iScroll + iPhone4 + retina + blurred text and adding that translate3d(0,0,0); to the entire body helped (as described in that link)